# Accessing container fields part 2

Tags: java, reference, jpanel

With respect to one of my previous threads [Accessing container fields part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086586/accessing-container-fields)I would like to ask the following:

I am designing an app using netbeans and currently having 3 components:

1)My main class (mainApp) which extends a JFrame
2)Two custom made classes which both extend a JPanel

Some days ago I faced some problems refering to my main class from within one on my JPanels
but hopefully thanks to "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" user I used the following method:
`app = (mainApp) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);`
and dealt with it.

Now I need to get a reference from within one of my JPanels for the other JPanel. For some strange reason though..it seems I can't do it..! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!
Solved using the following code:

        `//myFrame is my main class
        myFrame = (mainApp) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);

        Component[] comps = myApp.getContentPane().getComponents();


        int i =-1;

        do{
            i++;
 
        }

        //canvasPan is one of my custom-made JPanels

        while(!(comps[i] instanceof canvasPan));

        myCanvas = (canvasPan)comps[i];`